# bootstrap-select when setting container then the options will not hiding after selected?

Tags: bootstrap-select

bootstrap-select when setting container then the options will not hide after selected?

```
<form id="searchForm" action="" method="post" class="form-search">

   <label>section ：</label>

   <select name="section.id" class="" onchange="" id="section" tabindex="-98">

     <option value="35">S340NJ-LM2_ </option>

     <option value="16">S340NJ-</option>

   </select>
```

```
 $('select').selectpicker({
     container:'.form-search',
     liveSearch: true
 })
```

delete js line 2, will find

jsfiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/Seven4X/9ge8mcgp/

Answer (score 2):

You need to add the class to your select tag

```
class="selectpicker"
```

Comment: but when add selectpicker ,the float will scrolling